# Can `ls` be set to only list the first X files/directories?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, ls

I'm trying to make a command which only displays the first 30 files when the `ls` command is invoked.  I found this method...

```
ls | head -30
```

... but it ends up spitting out the files in one long list, not formatted in a row or colored as per the `.bash_profile`.  So, is there any way to simply limit the output?

Comment: What do you mean by "spitting out the files in one long list, not formatted in a row"?  In other words, formatted to your liking, what would it look like?

Comment: @John1024 Sorry, I meant in columns like `ls` does.  Basically I want the exact functionality of `ls`, just with trimmed results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Until asteri clarified the question, I thought John1024 had the answer. Now it seems that the following will work without the `--color` option:

```
ls -d $(ls | head -30)
```

Unfortunately this is too simplistic and will fail if there are blanks in the file names. To take account of that you need the more elaborate:

```
ls -b | head -30 | xargs ls -d
```

In both cases the principle is the same: `ls | head` gets the first 30 files, one per line, which are then presented as an argument list to another `ls` command, which needs the `-d` option in case any of the files are directories.

Comment: Wow!  Your second one works flawlessly.  Thank you!

Comment: Upon further testing, it actually breaks when a directory has a space in its name.  Still the best solution, though.

Comment: I checked that case before I answered and it worked for me (just checked again and it still works!). The only time that I can think of when it would fail is if there is a new-line character in the name, not a normal occurrence.

Comment: Are you on OSX or a normal Linux distro?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, but as I understand it there should be no differences in `bash` between the two systems - you have already found out that there are differences in available options of the support utilities, but the critical option `ls -b` is very basic, and should work in all implementations. Try the command by itself and check that all blanks are preceded by back-slashes, then make sure that `head -30` doesn't affect this.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  Neither `ls -b` nor `ls -B` are escaping the output.  No clue.  Thank you for the solution, though!

Comment: In that case `ls | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | tail -30 | xargs ls -d` will work for literal spaces, but not other white spaces.

Answer (score 4):

To get coloring:

```
ls -l --color=always | head -30
```

Normally, `ls` produces color only when the output is going directly to a terminal.  This is generally a good thing.  To override that, use `--color=always`

The above produces output with one file per line.  If you want, space allowing, more files per line, then try:

```
ls -l | head -30 | column
```

The column utility formats its input into multiple columns. The use of color may, however, confuse it.

Comment: I was in the middle of answering `ls -ld $(ls|head -30)`, with elaborations for files with embedded spaces, but this is much more straightforward.

Comment: Nice!  This is almost perfect.  Except that it's saying `ls: illegal option --`.  Is that not available on OSX?

Comment: (I just realized I had a wrong option in the example code, which is what lead to the confusion.  Just `ls | head -30 | column` did the trick, minus the color.)

Comment: @asteri I just checked the [OSX man page for `ls`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) and it does not appear to support the `--color` option.  The somewhat awkward work-around for color is to set the environment variables `CLICOLORS=true` and `CLICOLORS_FORCE=true`.  If this works for you (I have no access to OSX to test it), I would suggest putting it all in a shell script so that those variable settings are deleted when the script ends.

Comment: Using `export CLICOLOR_FORCE=true` did indeed work.  You were completely right, though, that it messed up the formatting of the columns.  This is perfect, though.  Thank you.  Wish I could give you more than one upvote.